# Why does fmod(55.8,9.3) return 9.3 when 55.8/9.3 =6?

Tags: floating-point, number-theory

I am trying to use the fmod function but I am not getting the results I am expecting.

Comment: One language per question please

Comment: I suspect it's a floating point rounding issue. Neither of those numbers can be represented exactly as a float.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It actually returns 9.299999999999994 due to floating point imprecision. Neither 55.8 or 9.3 can be exactly represented as a base 2 floating point number.

It's a very common problem. One good reference is [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Not being able to accurately present it is one thing, but how could this lead to a difference of over 3 with small numbers?

Comment: @Cubic, `fmod` returns the remainder of a division. In this case the division returned 5 instead of 6 because either 55.8 was rounded down or 9.3 was rounded up. The expected result of this fmod I'm sure was 0.0.

Comment: … and note that the solution is to add a fudge factor (or "tolerance" if you prefer) before performing the modulo, just as you always need to specify a fudge factor when testing for equality. If the fudge is `ε`, then you should be testing `fmod(55.8+ε,9.3) < 2ε` to see if the result was "zero."

Comment: @Potatoswatter: That is not a good resolution for floating-point issues using the fmod function. Just for example, it would not work in this case, since fmod returns a number slightly under 9.3, so testing whether it were under two times a small epsilon would produce `false`, but the asker apparently would be expecting `true`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The purpose of the fudge factor is to push any potential number just under 9.3 over the brink so it is instead close to 0. But it is true that this is an oversimplified solution; for numbers with a high dynamic range (which are the point of FP, after all) it is impossible to choose a good `ε`.

Comment: This is a useful answer, but it doesn't address the OP's actual confusion. He's apparently expecting fmod to return something close to 6—that is, the quotient, not the remainder. Once he gets past that and asks, "OK, so why isn't it 0?", this answer is perfect—but first he has to get that far.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: This method of decreasing false negatives increases false positives. Without knowing the requirements of the application, you cannot know whether this increase is harmless or a disaster. It is a bad recommendation. In some circumstances, NO value of epsilon suffices.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, you can multiply by (1+ε) instead of adding ε so that the fudge factor scales with the input.

Comment: @abarnert, it's not clear to me whether the OP is confused or just wrote the question poorly.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Scaling the first operand increases the error relative to the second operand, which is likely more critical (e.g., when reducing arguments for periodic functions). In fact, for continuous periodic functions, which side of the boundary the residue falls on is irrelevant, and modifying the fmod input merely increases the error without providing any benefit.

Comment: @MarkRansom: His first comment on this answer implies that he's confused, because I can't see how you could interpret "how could this lead to a difference of over 3 with small numbers" as expecting it to be 0 rather than 6.

Comment: @abarnert, that wasn't the OP.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Then maybe the OP just wrote a confusing question, and another user got confused, in which case your answer is all the OP needs.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yep, the next better solution is to multiply by `1+ε`, but then you also have to multiply `2ε` by `55.8`. Still that leaves negative values as a potential issue. This also changes the failure mode for epsilon greater than the modulus: the naive way will tend to `false` with a small and decreasing chance of `true`, whereas the improved way will tend toward `true` as epsilon approaches and surpasses the modulus.

Comment: @MarkRansom 

I think I may have wrote the question poorly. I meant I was expecting the result of fmod(55.8, 9.3) to be 0 since the division  55.8/9.3 = 6 with no remainder. Apologies for the confusion and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Like most decimal fractions, these numbers can't be represented exactly as binary floating point values. Assuming the most common implementation of `double`, the actual values are approximately:

```
55.799999999999997158
```

and:

```
9.3000000000000007105
```

These do not divide exactly, and the result of `fmod` is approximately:

```
9.2999999999999936051
```

which is rounded to `9.3` when displayed to a small number of decimal places.

These values were produced with the following C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::setprecision(20);

    double a = 55.8;
    double b = 9.3;

    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << fmod(a,b) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I had a strong hunch that this was the case since 
`55.8 = 5*9.3 + some rounding for (9.2999999999999936051) `

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you're expecting it to be somewhere near 6 implies that your problem isn't that you don't understand rounding, but that you don't know what `fmod` actually does.

`fmod` is the [remainder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder) of the division, not the quotient. That is, it's the amount left over after subtracting out an integral number of copies of the divisor. In mathematical terms, `a = q*b + r`, where `q = int(a/b)`, and `r = fmod(a, b)`.

If a and b were exactly 55.8 and 9.3, a/b would be exactly 6, and the remainder 0. So, it's perfectly reasonable for you to expect 0 as a result, and on some platforms that might be what you actually get.

However, on most platforms, the closest approximations possible to 55.8 and 9.3 are about 55.799999999999997158 and 9.3000000000000007105 (see Mark Ransom's answer for why), which means the quotient is 5.999999999999999, which means the integral part of the quotient is 5, which means the remainder is 55.799999999999997158 - 9.3000000000000007105 * 5 = 9.299999999999997, which is displayed as 9.3.

If you think about it, this makes sense. If the right remainder is 0, a small rounding error can't make the remainder 1 or 6; really all that's possible is something very near 0 or something very near 9.3. (If it helps, think about modulo 9.3 arithmetic, where 0 and 9.3 are the same number.)

Comment: He didn't he expected `fmod` to return 6 at all, he said that `55.8/9.3=6`, so it doesn't make sense that `fmod` returns 9.3.

Comment: @netcoder: "Not being able to accurately present it is one thing, but how could this lead to a difference of over 3 with small numbers?"

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. It returns 9.3, and you'd expect it to return 0, therefore the difference is more than 3. So... yeah.

Comment: @netcoder: Well, I suppose 9.3 is "more than 3", but 3.3 is a far more likely referent.

Comment: Why would I expect fmod to work like division and return 6?
Perhaps I wrote the question poorly. I was expecting the result to be 0 since the division returns 6. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the help.